# PHP MYSQL search same keyword with multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, search, full-text-search

I'm try to create a query which will search four different tables with one keyword to bring all the items which are list under that location.

I have four tables
- Country
- State 
- County 
- City

for e.g. UK -> England -> West Midlands -> Birmingham

When user types in west Midlands i wont to see all the items including items under birmingham, Walsall, wolverhampton

This what I came up with

```
$location = $_POST['location'];
$city_sql = " SELECT * FROM city";

$city_result = $db->query( $city_sql );
$new_array=array();
$i=0;
while ($fetch_sql = $db->fetch_object($city_result) ){

    if ( strcmp(soundex(strtolower($fetch_sql->name)), soundex(strtolower($location))) == 0 ) { 
        $new_array[$i]['name'] = $fetch_sql->name;
        $new_array[$i]['code'] = $fetch_sql->name;
        $i++; 
    }
}

$k=0;
for ( $j=0; $j < sizeof($new_array); $j++ ){
    $i = similar_text(strtolower($new_array[$j]['name']), strtolower($db->escape_value($location)), &$similarity_pst);
    if( $i > $k && $i > 7 ){
        $k = $i;
            $city_db_name = $new_array[$j]['name'];
            $city_code = $new_array[$j]['code'];
    }
}
```

Please let me know if you have any idea.

PHP MYSQL search same keyword with multiple tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use SQL features to get your data, not PHP's.

If I correctly understood, you want to get data from several tables and several columns.
Change your query like that:

```
SELECT
  -- list of considered columns
  col1,
  col2,
  col3
  -- ...
FROM
  City
JOIN
  State ON State.state_id = City.state_id
JOIN
  Country ON Country.country_id = State.country_id
WHERE
  col1 LIKE '%keyword%'
  OR col2 LIKE '%keyword%'
  OR col3 LIKE '%keyword%'
  -- ...
```

Like that, you will get columns you need containing your keyword. For example, if the table City contains {'Paris', 'paramatta', 'Porto'}, using the keyword **Par**, and the query `SELECT name FROM city WHERE name LIKE '%Par%'` will return you { 'Paris', 'paramatta' }

By the way, the link between countries, cities, etc. should be represented backward in your database: Country <- State <- City

Comment: I dont wont to do search all three cols. i wont to check to see which it does match and then show list by that col

Comment: e.g if its cloested to state then stop and show everything for that but if it matches the city then just disply that city.

Comment: also some cities are not in database user might wont to enter own cities. which will be in anohter table

Comment: Sorry i dont know how to explain this?

Comment: customize this query as you like to make it work with what you are doing. This query will have NULL columns where it does not match your keyword. Like that you'll be able to know which columns does (not null columns). I edit my post with an example.